# How to print a long list without indexes?

Tags: r

How to print a long list without indexes ?

The output I get :

```
> print(1:100)
 [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18
 [19]  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36
 [37]  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54
 [55]  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72
 [73]  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
 [91]  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100
```

Desired output :

```
> print(1:100)
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18
 19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36
 37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54
 55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72
 73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
 91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100
```

I tried with `cat()` function but it doesn't do line returns.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see my edit. doesn't give what I want

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A neat solution is `cat` but using its `fill` argument, in combination with the `format()` function.

```
cat(format(1:100), fill = getOption("width"))
```

which gives

```
> cat(format(1:100), fill = getOption("width"))
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20 
 21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40 
 41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60 
 61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80 
 81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100
```

I haven't tried this with all kinds of vectors to know if the filling/splitting is infallible but it might be sufficient for your needs if alignment is important.

The advantage of using `format()` here (rather than `paste()`) is that `format()` pads the individual strings to a common length

```
> format(1:10)
 [1] " 1" " 2" " 3" " 4" " 5" " 6" " 7" " 8" " 9" "10"
```

If you just `fill` the catted numeric vector or a pasted representation, the alignment is still off:

```
> cat(1:100, fill = getOption("width"))
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 
56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 
82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
> cat(paste(1:100), fill = getOption("width"))
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 
56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 
82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
```

Answer (score 10):

Try the option

```
 fill =TRUE
```

with

```
 cat()
```

Here is an example:

```
 > cat(paste(1:100), fill=TRUE)
```

It will break lines depending on the width of your screen.

Comment: plus 1, beat me by a second

Answer (score 4):

Consider using `writeLines()` and `strwrap()` on a suitably composed string:

```
writeLines(strwrap(paste(1:100, collapse = " ")))
```

which gives

```
> writeLines(strwrap(paste(1:100, collapse = " ")))
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51
52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75
76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
100
```

It's not quite what you want, but close. You would need to format each of the individual character elements to get the padding correct.

Part of the problem is that `strwrap()` destroys all whitespace...

Comment: plus one for `strwrap`